# Metro Bundler internal has encountered an internal error

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I'm starting to learn ReactNative with this tutorial : https://openclassrooms.com/fr/courses/4902061-developpez-une-application-mobile-react-native

Everything works fine but when we transform our app into a native one I can't compile it on android.

I always have this error when `react-native run-android` :

```
error: bundling failed: Invariant Violation: invalid asset resolution
at invariant (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\invariant\invariant.js:40:15)
at ModuleResolver._getFileResolvedModule (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:224:9)
at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ModuleResolution.js:159:19)
at ResolutionRequest.resolveDependency (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph\ResolutionRequest.js:52:18)
at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\node-haste\DependencyGraph.js:283:16)
at Object.resolve (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\lib\transformHelpers.js:261:42)
at dependencies.map.result (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:399:31)
at Array.map (<anonymous>)
at resolveDependencies (C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:396:18)
at C:\laragon\www\React\SampleReactNativeProject\node_modules\metro\src\DeltaBundler\traverseDependencies.js:269:33
```

And have this on the phone :

[image]

Here's my code : https://gitlab.com/baltus.remi/moviesandme

I already tryied to reinstall all the env, etc etc.
If I run-android un basic react-native app it's working like a charm ...

Thank for your help !

Answer (score 0):

Try deleting the app. Then clean the project run cd android && ./gradlew clean

Then come back to root directory cd..

Then again make a debug build react-native run-android or whatever your command is in script

Most of the time these steps are necessary if added new package.

Answer (score 0):

first of all run `npm install` then after that run `npm install --save-dev metro`

I ran into this same issue after many hours of trying to find the error, I found this helpful command and I tried it out and it worked
this command installed Metro locally